# AASM Gem broken by Rails 2.3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, aasm

Has anyone had any problems using the [AASM](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/tree/master) state machine Gem with Rails 2.3.2? It was working fine for me but is now giving a `NoMethodError`:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `state' for #<Comment:0x25cb8ac>):
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.0.5/lib/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:231:in `send'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.0.5/lib/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:231:in `aasm_read_state'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.0.5/lib/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:135:in `aasm_current_state'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.0.5/lib/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:156:in `aasm_ensure_initial_state'
 app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Here's the relevant code from my model that uses AASM:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM
  belongs_to :post          
  after_create :spam_check

  aasm_column :state
  aasm_initial_state :submitted
  aasm_state :submitted
  aasm_state :approved
  aasm_state :rejected

  aasm_event :ham do
    transitions :to => :approved, :from => [:submitted, :rejected]
  end

  aasm_event :spam do
    transitions :to => :rejected, :from => [:submitted, :approved]
  end     

  private          
  def spam_check
    # Invoke Askismet to see if the comment is spam...
  end
end
```

Note that I have the `state` column in my `comments` table.

- Any ideas why it no longer works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, you need a field in your comments table called 'state'. You defined it using `aasm_column :state`. This is not a Rails 2.3.2 bug! :D

Comment: I have that column in my comments table.

Comment: It turns out that I didn't have that column after all! It was defined in my migration and schema.rb, but I'm also running a SQL file to pre-populate the database and that had got slightly out of sync and was dropping the "state" column.

Answer (score 1):

From the [aasm home page](http://rubyi.st/aasm/) it appears that, as at time of writing, there's an update coming...

There's a little discussion on the [Ruby on Rails group](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/709e918b40d7d4e8/69b63a0dc88541c2?lnk=gst&q=aasm#69b63a0dc88541c2) - I don't know if any of that helps.

Executing

```
gem list .*aasm --remote
```

threw up a bunch of references:

```
aasmith-yodlee (0.0.1.20090301132701)
bloom-aasm (2.0.3)
bloom-bloom-aasm (2.0.3)
caleb-aasm (2.0.2)
dunedain289-aasm (2.1.3)
dvdplm-aasm (2.0.6)
eric-aasm (2.0.4)
factorylabs-aasm (2.0.5.2)
gvaughn-aasm (2.0.4)
lostboy-aasm (2.0.5.1)
mikowitz-aasm (2.0.6)
netguru-aasm (2.0.6)
notch8-aasm (2.0.5)
rubyist-aasm (2.0.5)
runcoderun-aasm (2.0.5.1)
snoozer05-aasm (2.0.2)
spicycode-aasm (2.0.0)
```

It suspect that some or all of the "dvdplm-", "factorylabs-" and "runcoderun-" ones may be git forks. You may find that one or more fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried swapping out rubyist-aasm for factorylabs-aasm, but it still doesn't work. I'm going to try creating a brand new Rails project with a simple state machine model and see if it works for that.